# Return second column if i know first in visual studio from access database

Tags: c#, ms-access

I'm making this program which tells me the antonym of inserted word. Basically, I have a textBox and a button. Text from textbox is being searched for a match from database and i want to return the column next to it, containing the antonym of a given word. Here's the code:

```
 private void btnFind_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OleDbCommand command1 = new OleDbCommand();
    command1.Connection = connection;
    command1.CommandText = "select * from antonymsdb where '" + txtWord.Text + "' = word";
    OleDbDataReader reader = command1.ExecuteReader();
    int count = 0;
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        count++;
    }
    if (count == 1)
    {
        //word has been found and i want to take the word from the column next to this one and put it in a variable
    }
}
```

word is a column of the antonymsdb database from Access.

Comment: reader[index] or reader[column name].  Then cast to type.

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand, can you explain, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are getting a single value (antonym) then do not use a reader. Just use the `ExecuteScalar` method:

```
OleDbCommand command1 = new OleDbCommand();
command1.Connection = connection;
command1.CommandText = 
   "select nameOfColumn from antonymsdb where word ='" + txtWord.Text + "'";
string antonym = command1.ExecuteScalar().ToString();  
connection.Close();
```

If you are expecting more than one then do this:

```
var antonyms = new List<string>();
while (reader.Read())
{
    antonyms.Add(reader.GetString(putIndexOfColumnHere));
}
```

Also make sure you read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work) because your code is open to sql injections.

Comment: Doesn't really work. I don't know if I explained well. So far, I have code that searches database and finds the word. I just don't know how to take the word with the same ID, primary key, same row, just column called antonym, not word..

Comment: See my edit. You need to fix your query. Make sure to put the names of your columns in my query because I do not know the names of your columns.